# Finding the area by Green's Theorem

Tags: integration, area, mathematical-modeling, greens-theorem

If I have

$\ x=\sin^3t$ and $\ y = \cos^3t$

I'm using Green's theorem to calculate the area enclosed by the curve  via integration, but at the end I'm getting negative area $-3\pi/8$, which is wrong.

Do I need to calculate by the absolute value? I know that if $\ x=\cos^3t$ and $\ y = \sin^3t$, the answer will be $3\pi/8$, but what to do with this? Why does the sign change value for different paramterization?

This is the formula, which I used;
$\frac{1}{2}$ $\int_0^{2π }(x(t).y'(t)-x'(t).y(t))dt $

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150247/discussion-on-question-by-mohaboko-finding-the-area-by-greens-theorem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for obtaining a negative answer is the fact that when you parametrize using the first method, you are moving in the clockwise direction. Thus, the value you will obtain will be negative.

In the second parametrization, the direction you are moving in is the counterclockwise direction, which is the default convention followed while using Green's Theorem. That is why you are obtaining a positive value.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150246/discussion-on-answer-by-scipio-aemilianus-finding-the-area-by-greens-theorem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(x,y)=(\sin^3t,\cos^3t)$$
At $t=0$, $P$ is $A(0,1).$
At $t=\frac\pi 2$, $P$ is $B(1,0)$.
At $t=\pi$, $P$ is $C(0,-1)$.
At $t=\frac{3\pi}2$, $P$ is $D(-1,0)$.
At $t=2\pi$, $P$ is $A(1,0)$ again.

We see that orientation is clockwise. In Green's theorem, the contour is oriented counter clockwise. Therefore the integration route will be $BADCB$ not $ABCDA$. So,
$$\int_{C}\frac12(xdy-ydx)\\=\int_C\frac{3\cos(4t)-3}{16}dt\\=4
\int_{\overset{\frown}{BA}}\frac{3\cos(4t)-3}{16}dt\\
=\int_{\frac\pi 2}^0\frac{3\cos(4t)-3}{4}dt=\frac{3\pi}{8}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. So we just did Integration from Pi/2 to 0, not from 0 to Pi/2, right?

Comment: @Mohaboko Yes.  I think of it as a movement. When you move from $B$  to $A$, the parameter changes from $\pi/2$ to $0$.

Comment: Well. Thank you.